# MySQL: InnoDB data dictionary has unknown flags

Tags: mysql, innodb

I tried to delete and recreate a MySQL service and when I tried to start the service again I can't start it and I'm getting this error in error logs:

**InnoDB: Warning: table 'sampledb/table1' InnoDB: in InnoDB data dictionary has unknown flags 50.**

What could be the possible cause why I'm encountering this error?

Here is the sample error logs generated when I'm trying to start the service I have recreated:

```
200121 13:32:48 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
200121 13:32:48 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
200121 13:32:48 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
200121 13:32:48 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
200121 13:32:48 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 2.0G
200121 13:32:49 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
200121 13:32:49  InnoDB: Log file .\ib_logfile0 did not exist: new to be created
InnoDB: Setting log file .\ib_logfile0 size to 48 MB
InnoDB: Database physically writes the file full: wait...
200121 13:32:49  InnoDB: Log file .\ib_logfile1 did not exist: new to be created
InnoDB: Setting log file .\ib_logfile1 size to 48 MB
InnoDB: Database physically writes the file full: wait...
200121 13:32:50 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
InnoDB: The log sequence number in ibdata files does not match
InnoDB: the log sequence number in the ib_logfiles!
200121 13:32:50  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
InnoDB: Last MySQL binlog file position 0 386, file name mysql_bin.000027
200121 13:32:53  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
200121 13:32:54 InnoDB: 5.5.60 started; log sequence number 77829315084
200121 13:32:54 [ERROR] Aborting

200121 13:32:54  InnoDB: Warning: table 'sampledb/table1'
InnoDB: in InnoDB data dictionary has unknown flags 50.
200121 13:32:54  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
200121 13:32:55  InnoDB: Warning: table 'sampledb/table2'
InnoDB: in InnoDB data dictionary has unknown flags 50.
200121 13:32:55  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 77829315084
200121 13:32:55 [Note]
```

This is how I recreated the MySQL service:

```
mysqld --install MySQL56 --defaults-file=D:\MySQL\5.6.40\my.ini
```

Comment: (https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=72371)  See, for example, https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/183706/issues-after-schemas-migration-from-mysql-4-to-mysql-5-6

Comment: @Akina but I can't start the MySQL service

Comment: Try [Forcing InnoDB Recovery](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html). Do not forget to make file backup of datadir before.

Comment: @Akina I already tried it but it is still not working.

Answer (score 1):

you probably have multi different version binary of mysql installed in your server, make sure you are in the correct version path...